# Is it allowed to sacrifice one day after Eid-ul-Adha?

Tags: eid, sacrifice

Is allowed to sacrifice on the second and third days after Eid-ul-Adha. And how many days does Eid-ul-Adha last - is it just 1 day or 3 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sacrifice 3 days after the Eid day (total 4 days).

> Ibn al-Qayyim (may Allaah have mercy on him) said in Zaad al-Ma’aad
>   (2/319):
>
> ‘Ali ibn Abi Taalib (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: “The days of
>   sacrifice are the Day of Sacrifice (yawm al-nahr) and the three days
>   after it.”

Source: http://www.islam-qa.com/en/36651